# VBA MS-WORD: Is it possible to use .MoveUntil Cset is equal to any character?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Like for example `"sampletext^p^p^p"` where `"^p"` is the carriage return. I want to move from the last `"^p"` to the left until it reach any character from A to Z like for the example above is `"t"`. Is it possible? And I also want it be extend so it would select from the last `"^p"` to `"t"`.

I tried to use `.MoveUntil cset:="?", count:=wdBackward` since that in wildcard, `?` is considered as any single character but it only move backward until it find the ? character.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. What have you tried and how did it not work?

Comment: Nope, I tried to use `.MoveUntil cset:="?", count:=wdBackward` since that in wildcard, `?` is considered as any single character but it only move backward until it find the `?` character. If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

These "Move" methods don't support wild cards. The value you hand to CSet has to contain the literal string characters. There are (at least) two ways you can accomplish what you postulate:

```
Range.MoveStartUntil Cset:="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", Count:=wdBackward
```

OR

```
Range.MoveStartWhile cSet:=vbCr, count:=wdbackward
```

Note: also works with the Selection object.